# How can I trigger ngOnChanges only after every input values has been set in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ngoninit, ngonchanges

How can I trigger ngOnChanges only after every input values has been set in ngOnInit.
My code -->

```
`ngOnInit() {
this.multiSelectorData.forEach(item=>{
            this.allItems.push(item.data);
        });
}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes['dataReady'] && changes['dataReady'].currentValue) {
   console.log(this.allItems);
}`
```

I wont get the array I initialized in ngonit in ngonchanges because ngonchanges is called before ngonit, how can i check if all are initialized before checking ngonchanges?